# Meaning of $\mu t$ terms in dependent type theory

Tags: type-theory, dependent-types

What is the meaning of the term $\mu t$ in the type theory formalized in [this paper (section 2.1, page 2)](https://fermat.github.io/document/papers/scott-dep.pdf)?

Answer (score 3):

The term `μ t` is the application of a closure `μ` to a term `t`. Similar to how `t t'` is the application of a term `t` to `t'`.